# PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback MediaPlayer IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xC8

Tags: android

I want to play video from a URL via HTTP. I read [Media Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) and other stackoverflow questions. Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://..../myVideo.mp4"
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

`mediaPlayer.prepare()` is throwing IOException: Prepare failed. For the test purpose I record a video using my mobile phone and then I put the mp4 file to server.

Comment: Have you sreated your mediaplayer using mediaplayer.create()?

Comment: Look at this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650983/server-side-aac-audio-with-android
Hoping find this useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this line from stack trace:

```
08-17 14:36:58.005: ERROR/PlayerDriver(1943): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error 
                                    or info PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback
```

The problem is: my video is not capable of progressive download.

The only solution I figured out is using `MP4Box` which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box).

To make video ready for android I just run `MP4Box.exe -hint myVideo.mp4`.

Comment: is this the answer or a part of the question?

Comment: Yes this is the answer. I edited my answer with detailed explanation.